SQL error when a temporary table can't be made using #
I tried to use "eMERGE OMOP MS SQL version of the original T2DM case algorithm" in the https://phekb.org/phenotype/type-2-diabetes-mellitus. When I run the code I got this error: "Syntax error at or near '#'". The problem should be in here:
SELECT event_id, person_id, start_date, end_date, 
     op_start_date, op_end_date, visit_occurrence_id

INTO #qualified_events

FROM 
(
  select pe.event_id, pe.person_id, pe.start_date, pe.end_date,
    pe.op_start_date, pe.op_end_date, 
    row_number() over (partition by pe.person_id order by pe.start_date ASC) as ordinal, 
    pe.visit_occurrence_id
  FROM primary_events pe

I tried to make a temporary table instead of using '#', but the error exists. Any suggestion would help me a lot. Thanks.

Is it mySQL or MS SQL Server? # prefix is used in MS SQL Server for temp tables.

While MySQL documentation doesn't explicitly list every disallowed character, it implies that any character that is problematic for the file system (like #, %, or /) or that has special meaning in SQL (like " or ') should be avoided unless the identifier is quoted. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

I challenge the premise: in my experience, the vast majority of places I've seen temp tables used, the temp table was not actually needed or helpful.

If it is MySQL, then write it like:
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_qualified_events AS (

  select pe.event_id, pe.person_id, pe.start_date, pe.end_date,
    pe.op_start_date, pe.op_end_date, 
    row_number() over (partition by pe.person_id order by pe.start_date ASC) as ordinal, 
    pe.visit_occurrence_id
  FROM primary_events pe
);

'#' prefix is for MS SQL temp tables.
EDIT: You can see a demo here created with version 5.7 of MySQL DBFiddle demo

Thanks Cetin, I used what you have suggested but got the error: "Syntax error at or near 'CREATE'.(line 41, pos 0)"

@Sana, I believe you typed something wrong.  And you didn't really tell what your backend is.

I did tell the error exactly and referenced the query that I used. Since the server is not MS SQL it does not support '#'. So I need to find an alternative way to make a temporary table that can fit in the rest of the query.

@Sana I gave you sample code to create a temporary table in MySQL and also I added a demo for you. https://dbfiddle.uk/wZP347fe Are you sure you don't have some other code that might cause this or the database you are using may not be MySQL?

The issue was related to this part of the code that I typed. However, you can see the entire code in the "eMERGE OMOP MS SQL version of the original T2DM case algorithm" file in the https://phekb.org/phenotype/type-2-diabetes-mellitus. The issue is in the line 125. Thanks.

@Sana, you assume we can see the code in the link you provided but we cannot. It doesn't allow me to reach there. Why wouldn't you directly share the code here (maybe few lines before and after the script that is in question).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The code is too long. I shared some part of it in the chat. Thanks.
